# How to hide sharing screen in Apple watch

Tags: apple-watch

Open Activity rings in Apple watch and then swipe left. `Sharing` screen is shown.

`Sharing` screen says "To start sharing your Activity. Use Activity app on iPhone". How to hide this screen completely in Apple Watch.

Comment: You might want to be more specific about where you see that and/or share screenshots. I wear a series 2 watch daily and can't recall ever seeing what you are talking about.

Comment: I see that screen on my Series 2 watch but I don't know what you're trying to do by hiding it.  Have you setup friends to share your activities according to [Apple's directions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207014)?

Comment: No. I don't want to share the activity. So I want to hide that screen. Seems not possible.

Comment: My reading of Apple's directions *seem* to indicate that adding users on the iPhone app will show those users names and not that useless screen. I don't have anyone to test this with so I can't validate my assumption.